# IE9+ : check if an ActiveX control is installed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Thanks to a few try/catch I can determine if the plugin is activated ... now I'd like to know if it's installed or if it needs to be downloaded.

It seems that all the solutions that I find are obsolete :

- there's no `navigator.plugins` array
- `new ActiveXObject('SomeActiveX')` causes an exception `SCRIPT429: ActiveX component can't create object`
- `document.getElementById('controlId')` retrieves null

How can I get the 'State' property of a specified ActiveX control ?

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception that is thrown.

```
try { 
   new ActiveXObject('SomeActiveX'); 
} catch(e) { 
   alert("nope"); 
}
```

Comment: This always retrieve "nope" : new ActiveXObject causes a 'SCRIPT429' exception.

Comment: When it is not supported it will go into the catch, that is how it works.

Comment: Currently the plugin is loaded + activated, but new ActiveXObject('..') causes a SCRIPT429 ... It seems that a security option blocks this action [(see here)](http://www.aras.com/Community/forums/p/2527/7698.aspx). But anyway it would probably also 'crash' if the plugin is simply desactived, so I would say that's not the flag I'm looking for ..